# visual studio 2010 include directory paths

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, include, include-path

I have a visual studio solution myvs.sln with the following path: `c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\myvs\myvs\myvs.sln`. I have boost version xxx installed in `c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\boostxxx\`.

I have in the project->properties->c/c++->general: `../..;../../boostxxx`. Inside boost libraries the include files have the following syntax: `#include <boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr>`.

My code file `myfile.h` resides in `c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\yy1\myfile.h`. In myfile.h I include boost libraries as: `#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>`. I am getting a error which says: `c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\yyy1/myfile.h fatal error C1083 cannot open include file boost/shared_ptr.hpp`.

The question is what should I do to correct this?

I also notice that the error output the compiler throws has "\" upto dir3 and then changes to "/".

Most probably I do not understand how the relative path is working. Also note that I want to refer to only relative path not absolute paths. Can someone please help? I am in windows platform using c++ visual studio 2010.

Comment: Q: Do you have (all!) boost header directories in your Visual Studio "include" list?  Are they separated by ";"?

Comment: no i only have base directory where i have installed boost that is only: ../../boostxxx. in the include path list

Answer (score 3):

Relative paths *in the search paths* refer to <del>the directory of the file with the `#include` directive</del> the current directory of the compiler, some simple testing now shows.

"..\.." is going up two levels from <del>your header file</del> the current directory of the compiler instead of from your project directory.

To fix this, explicitly start your include paths in your Visual Studio project directory, as follows (literally):

> $(ProjectDir)..\..;$(ProjectDir)..\..\BoostXXX

Regarding forward versus backward slash, use forward slash in your C++ code's `#include` directives, because that's most portable.

Use either forward or backward slash (but I prefer backwards slash so as to have a single convention) where you're referring to the Windows file system, such as in the setup of include paths.