# File Path Concatenation

Tags: python, windows, path, concatenation, pathlib

I need to build a Windows (only) file path from a combination of a UNC path passed to my script as a parameter, an API call, and a calculated date.

I'm having a horrible time of it, mostly caused by Windows' use of a backslash character to delimit file paths. I've read that the "pathlib" module should be able to sort this mess out, BUT it apparently doesn't support concatenation when building out file paths.

The UNC path is being passed out to the script as a dictionary from another application (PRTG Network Monitor:

```
{"fileshare": "//server02/logs/"}
```

I read that in and then need to append a hostname derived from an API call:

```
logPath = Path(params["fileshare"] + "/" + apiHostname + "/")
```

I then calculate a date which needs to be appended to the logpath, along with a delimiter "-" and a filename suffix:

```
filePath = Path(logPath, + apiHostname + "-", + past_day + ".log" )
```

The problem arises during the concatenation:

```
{"text": "Python Script execution error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WindowsPath' and 'str'", "error": 1}}
```

Can someone please explain how I can build a path so that the calculated filename, which should look like this:

```
\\server02\logs\log01.rhmgmt.lan\log01.rhmgmt.lan-2021-07-28.log
```

Can be opened for processing?

Comment: `Path(params["fileshare"] + "/" + apiHostname + "/")` looks wrong. You usually call these functions with comma-separated arguments and it does the concatenation for you. Usually I use `os.path.join(foo, bar, baz)`. `logPath, + apiHostname` is just a typo -- there's a hanging `+` in the middle of the argument list -- remove that.

Comment: Can't you use the [`joinpath()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.joinpath) method to concatenate them?

Comment: If you are using `pathlib.Path` then you should be using its functionality - the `/` operator - to join up paths, not string concatenation. Also note that *forward slashes work just fine for Windows paths in normal circumstances*; `cmd.exe` accepts them (they just mess with tab completion etc.) and Python programs accept them. [C++ programs accept them, too,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29119638/why-path-in-vs-c-contains-forward-slash-not-backslash) and it seems to be implemented on the Windows side.

Answer (score 0):

Yes *"pathlib" module should be able to sort this mess out*

Input:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from pathlib import Path

params = {"fileshare": "//server02/logs/"}
apiHostname = 'log01.rhmgmt.lan'
past_day = str((date.today() - timedelta(days=1)))
```

Create the initial path and append all parts:

```
fileshare = Path(params['fileshare'])
filepath = fileshare / apiHostname / f"{apiHostname}-{past_day}.log"
```

Output:

```
>>> filepath
PosixPath('//server02/logs/log01.rhmgmt.lan/log01.rhmgmt.lan-2021-07-28.log')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `pathlib` can easily sort things out.
You can use the [`joinpath()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.joinpath) method, as I suggested in a comment, to concatenate the components are you're building the `Path`. It does the equivalent of what [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) does.

The only slightly tricky part is you'll have to initially create an empty `Path` in order use the method they inherit from `PurePath`.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from pathlib import Path

params = {"fileshare": "//server02/logs/"}
apiHostname = 'log01.rhmgmt.lan'
past_day = str((date.today() - timedelta(days=1)))

filePath = Path().joinpath(params["fileshare"], apiHostname, 
                           apiHostname + '-' + past_day + '.log')
print(filePath)  # -> \\server02\logs\log01.rhmgmt.lan\log01.rhmgmt.lan-2021-07-29.log
```